# memory impact and scope/lifespan of imported modules python

Tags: python

I'm wondering about a few things concerning importing modules.
I have a module that contains nothing but a list of variables, so that I can use these across 3 or 4 scripts that run either once or daily.
This same module I would like to use in another script of mine, but I only need to load it once, and afterwards, I don't need the module anymore, because I would copy the variables to a list in my script(for comparison purposes).
My questions:
1. if I import the module in a method, is it discarded when the function ends?
2. what is the memory-impact on importing a module?

Good to know is that the function is one-shot.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually unload a module from python, it will be garbage collected if it is not referenced anymore :

```
del sys.modules["mymodule"]
del mymodule
```

Answer (score 2):

A reference to the module is stored in `sys.modules`, so no it's not released.

Consider using `execfile` or similar if you don't want to load the module